# golang exception to rule "interface pointer can't implement interface"

Tags: pointers, go, interface, implements

In golang.org's official FAQ, [under pointers](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Pointers) there is this quote:
*"The insight is that although a pointer to a concrete type can satisfy an interface, with one exception a pointer to an interface can never satisfy an interface"*

Out of curiosity, what is that exception to the above rule?
i.e when can an interface pointer implement an interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just below it says:

> The one exception is that any value, even a pointer to an interface,
>   can be assigned to a variable of empty interface type (interface{}).
>   Even so, it's almost certainly a mistake if the value is a pointer to
>   an interface; the result can be confusing.

Comment: You are right, I just tested it and it runs OK. Thanks
func main() {
 type I interface{}
 f := func(p interface{}) { fmt.Println("runs") }
 var i I = 1
 f(&i)
}